# In R, apply a complicated function (not base) on several columns by group (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a data frame, `df`, on which I would like to run a the function `kepdf` (from the package `pdfCluster` which calculates multivariate density). The point is this is not a simple base function like head, mean and the likes.

My data frame looks like this:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      A     B     C Group
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
      2     1    39     1
      2     2    66     1
      2     2    36     1
      1     1    56     1
      1     1    37     1
      1     1    45     1
```

Now, I would like to calculate the density of columns `A`, `B`, and `C` for each `Group` separately (the variable `Group` just indicates the group the observation belongs to and should not enter the density calculation). I naively tried the following:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% select(1:3) %>% do(kepdf(.))
```

and got the following error:

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `Group`
Error in kepdf(.) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
```

Now, there are no missing values in the data, so I'm confused. Also, I don't want to add the grouping variable `Group` because then the algorithm will add it to the density calculation, which I don't want it to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you mean `pdfCluster`?

Comment: yes, see edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're grouping your data.frame by `Group` then trying to discard the grouping column before performing `kepdf(...)`. When you call `do(...)`, it adds back the grouping column necessarily.

Try instead

```
library(purrr)
df %>% split(.$Group) %>% map(., ~select(.x, 1:3)) %>% map(., ~kepdf(.x))
```

You can always combine the last two `map(...)` into a single function

```
myfun <- function(df) {
    require(pdfCluster)
    data <- select(df, 1:3)
    kepdf(data)
}

df %>% split(.$Group) %>% map(., ~myfun(.x))
```